# Wildcard Matching: LeetCode 44 Attempt 2

Tags: c++, c++17, pattern-matching

Original [post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/283261/507):

Based on feedback from [J-H](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/145459/j-h) in his [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283267/507) I have done another attempt.

Link to [question](https://leetcode.com/problems/wildcard-matching/description/):

> Given an input string (s) and a pattern (p), implement wildcard pattern matching with support for '?' and '*' where:
>
> '?' Matches any single character.
> '*' Matches any sequence of characters (including the empty sequence).
>
> The matching should cover the entire input string (not partial).

Note:

The framework provides the class Solution and the method bool isMatch(string s, string  p) where you are supposed to implement the solution. I modified the method slightly.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

class Solution {
    using Word  = std::string_view;
    using Words = std::vector<Word>;

    // Check a single character match.
    bool check(char p, char s)
    {
        return p == '?' || p == s;
    }
    // Try and match "word" to text starting at point pos.
    bool match(Word const& word, std::string_view text, std::size_t pos)
    {
        text.remove_prefix(std::min(pos, text.size()));
        return text.size() >= word.size() && std::equal(std::begin(word), std::end(word), std::begin(text), [&](auto p, auto s){return check(p,s);});
    }
    // Match a list of "words" against the text in order.
    // Each word may be have a prefix in text that is ignored.
    // Note:
    // Remove the matched text from the input "text"
    // Return true if all words matched.
    bool matchWords(Words const& words, std::string_view& text)
    {
        std::size_t word = 0;
        std::size_t loop = 0;
        for (; loop < text.size() && word < words.size(); ++loop) {
            if (match(words[word], text, loop)) {
                loop += words[word].size() - 1;
                ++word;
            }
        }
        text.remove_prefix(std::min(loop, text.size()));
        return word == words.size();
     }
     // Split the text into a list of words separated by '*'
     Words splitWordsOut(std::string const& p)
     {
        Words   result;

        char const* begin = nullptr;
        char const* end   = nullptr;
        bool        split = true;
        for (auto& c: p) {
            if (c == '*') {
                split = true;
            }
            else {
                if (split) {
                    if (begin != nullptr) {
                        result.emplace_back(begin, std::distance(begin, end));
                    }
                    begin = &c;
                    end   = begin;
                }
                ++end;
                split = false;
            }
        }
        if (begin != nullptr) {
            result.emplace_back(begin, std::distance(begin, end));
        }
        return result;
    }
public:
    bool isMatch(std::string const& s, std::string const& p)
    {
        // Trivial test.
        // By doing this test here we don't need to check for empty string in other checks.
        if (p == "") {
            return s == "";
        }
        // Check for leading and trailing stars.
        bool                leadingStar    = p.front() == '*';
        bool                trailingStar   = p.back()  == '*';
        std::string_view    text(s);
        Words               words = splitWordsOut(p);

        // If there is not a trailing star the expression is anchored to the end of the string
        // So we need to test the last word matches the exact end of the string.
        if (!trailingStar && words.size() != 0) {
            if (!match(words.back(), text, text.size() - words.back().size())) {
                return false;
            }
            text.remove_suffix(words.back().size());
            words.pop_back();
        }

        // If the last character is not a star we have already tested and removed it.
        // This means the in the final matching we can match any unmatched text automatically
        // unless there is only one word not prefixed by a star.
        //   See: the final return on how this is used.
        bool                lastStar = words.size() != 0 || leadingStar;

        // If the first word is not prefixed by start then the first word is anchored to
        // the beginning. So see if we can match it.
        if (!leadingStar && words.size() != 0) {
            if (!match(words.front(), text, 0)) {
                return false;
            }
            text.remove_prefix(words.front().size());
            words.erase(words.begin());
        }
        // At this point all words have a star prefix.
        // So when doing matches we can ignore any leading characters that don't match.
        // So now we just need to see if we can find each word in the text in order.
        return matchWords(words, text) && (text.empty() || lastStar);
    }
};
```

Test Harness:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Solution    s;
    std::cout << "Result: 1 == " << s.isMatch("aa", "aa") << "\n\n\n\n";
    std::cout << "Result: 1 == " << s.isMatch("adceb", "*a*b") << "\n\n\n\n";
    std::cout << "Result: 0 == " << s.isMatch("mississippi", "m??*ss*?i*pi") << "\n\n\n\n";
    std::cout << "Result: 1 == " << s.isMatch("aaaa", "***a") << "\n\n\n\n";
}
```

Running it a few times.
Got runtimes of usually 6 -> 9 ms range.
Best runtime was 0ms (got a lucky run on a non busy machine) Beating 100% of the other entries. Has memory usage of 6.6MB, beating 96.51% of entries in Memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

## Move your code out of `class Solution`

> I modified the method slightly.

If you no longer feel bound by the interface imposed on you by LeetCode, then I would not put your code inside a `class` at all. Instead, write a free function `isMatch()` that takes `std::string_view`s as parameters. You can keep a stub `class Solution` that calls your code:

```
namespace {
    // Previously private functions can go into an anonymous namespace.
    …
}

bool isMatch(std::string_view text, std::string_view pattern) {
    …
}

class Solution {
public:
    bool isMatch(std::string s, std::string p) {
        return ::isMatch(s, p);
    }
};
```

## Avoid one-letter variable names

The LeetCode question might have primed you to use short variable names, however this is bad practice. Use one-letter variable names only for very commonly used things, like `i` for a loop iterator.

## Use `.empty()` consistently

You use `.empty()` in a few cases, but elsewhere you compare strings to `""`, or check that `.size()` is equal or unequal to zero. Use `.empty()` instead. While it doesn't matter much for `std::string` and `std::string_view`, there are other STL containers where `.empty()` might be much faster than any other method of checking if the container has any elements in it. It also unequivocally expresses your intent.

## Make more use of `std::string_view`

`splitWordsOut()` still takes a reference to a `std::string` as a parameter. I would pass it a `std::string_view` instead. It also seems to me that it has to check for leading stars (because of `begin != nullp[tr), and it's easy to tell if there is a trailing star (when` split == true` after the loop). So maybe have it return both the words and whether there were leading and/or trailing stars?

```
struct SplitWordsResults {
    bool leadingStar;
    bool trailingStar;
    Words words;
};

SplitWordsResults splitWords(std::string_view pattern)
{
    SplitWordsResults results{};
    …
    return results;
}
…
bool isMatch(std::string_view text, std::string_view pattern)
{
    if (pattern.empty()) {
        return text.empty();
    }

    auto [leadingStar, trailingStar, words] = splitWords(pattern);
    …
}
```

## Don't pass `const` references to `std::string_view`s

Your function `match()` takes a `const` reference to a `Word`, which is the same as a `std::string_view`. That is rather redundant.

I think it's better not to declare the type aliases `Word` and `Words`. I don't think it saved any typing, and since it obscures the actual type, mistakes like this are easier to make.

## Inadequate test suite

You only test a handful of combinations of texts and patterns, and this is by far not covering all the possible cases. I am missing empty patterns and texts, I am missing patterns that end with stars, I don't see any patterns with words that only consist of question marks, and so on.

While LeetCode probably throws a large variety of test cases at your program, don't trust that it will cover everything.

## Further performance improvements

In `splitWordsOut()` you could reserve enough memory for `result` so it only ever needs to do one memory allocation:

```
result.reserve((pattern.size() + 1) / 2);
```

You can also be smarter when `match()` fails. Consider that if you have a text like:

```
aaaaabaaaaac
```

And you have a pattern:

```
*aaaaac*
```

Then when `match()` is called with `pos = 0`, it will start comparing the start of the text with the word of the pattern. This all goes well until it sees the `b`, then it fails. You then try again with `pos = 1`, but at this point you actually know that this will fail to match as well. Instead, you can skip immediately to `pos = 5`, at least with *this* pattern, since `b` is not a character that matches anything in the pattern. If you replace the `b` with an `a` in the text, then you could not skip that much, because maybe the `c` would have been right after where the `b` was.

Given the pattern you can build a [finite state automaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) that will try to match the text against the pattern, and such that when it finds a mismatch, it knows exactly how much of the text it can skip. This is actually a large part of what `std::regex()` does. I already explained [earlier](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/283268/129343) that this could actually be bad for performance. However, there might be a middle ground where you have a few simple heuristics that are cheap to implement but can greatly speed up some of the cases. Since you already beat 100% of the other LeetCode entries, that might not be worth pursuing though.

Comment: Thanks. Agree with all that (I am changing the code). What is the name of this construct? `auto [leadingStar, trailingStar, words] = splitWords(pattern);`. Unit tests are based on the tests that failed in LeetCode and I was trying to test offline :-)

Comment: It's called a [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding), it was introduced in C++17.

Comment: I changed the structure `SplitWordsResults` into a `std::tuple<bool, bool, Words>` as the return type. Then return `{leadingStar, trailingStar, regExpWords}` then used the `structure binding` to unpack it at the call site.

Comment: I would avoid using `std::tuple` if you can make a `struct` just as easily. The advantage of a `struct` is that you can give it and its members names, so it's much more self-documenting than a `std::tuple` is. You can still use the statement `return {leadingStar, trailingStar, regExpWords}` even if the return type is a `struct`.

Comment: Interesting argument for not using tuple. I can definitely see the self documenting part. Going to have to think about that.